# Why are BLDC motors DC motors? They work on AC by using inverter. Can I directly give AC supply to a BLDC motor?

Tags: brushless-dc-motor

What I have heard is that BLDC is the workhorse in industry. Even laptop fans are BLDC.

Why are they called DC motors? They use an inverter to get AC as input. Can I directly give AC supply to a BLDC motor without an inverter? Is BLDC a misnomer or does it have some significance?

Comment: Theoretically yes. In practical terms there is no reason for it. What do you expect to gain?

Comment: I am working on e-rickshaw BLDC motor is used in it so I wanted to know if there are other possibilities in terms of motor ?

Comment: Again, why? What's wrong with the inverter it came with?

Comment: To really understand, read about how synchronous AC motors are started. If you just apply AC directly, they won't start under load, acting like an almost dead short across the AC supply. And BLDC motors would do the same.

Comment: What's in a name...?

Comment: Yes, it's a misnomer.

Answer (score 2):

BLDC motors, or brushless Direct current motors, are, as the name suggests, motors which have no brushes and are powered from DC.

You are correct, they use a style of inverter to convert from DC to a waveform which switches to activate the windings of the motor as required. However, this is not an AC motor, as an AC motor is tuned to operate at a speed to use the fluctuations of the supplied AC. The BLDC unit is designed to operate from DC which is switched as required by the motor. AC motors tend to be large, steady state, single speed style of motors powered by mains electricity. BLDCs are a lot better at handling different speeds (in very general terms).

An AC motor is defined from the AC supply. The "inverter" of the DC motor is defined from the motor.

Comment: Wouldn't this mean that an induction motor is a BLDC if it is driven by an inverter? I don't know if it's true or not, but sounds... weird somehow.

Comment: @HarrySvensson An induction motor is a form of brushless motor. If the motor is driven by an inverter, then it is a form of BLDC. If it relies on a fixed frequency of AC input, then it would be a form of AC motor.

Answer (score 2):

All motors are basically AC motors in principle: they rely on varying a magnetic field in a circular fashion to produce forces that turn the shaft. That ‘varying magnetic field’ is what the inverter (or, commutator) is controlling when it converts DC to coil drive voltages for a BLDC.

So you’re basically correct: a 3-phase induction motor is remarkably similar to a BLDC without its inverter.  As it is, if you feed a 3-phase waveform of appropriate voltage to the BLDC coils, it will spin too.

They differ in that the induction motor has a rotor designed to generate back-emf to make the attracting field, while the BLDC uses permanent magnets or a field coil.

Here’s the thing. The 3-phase AC induction motor runs at or near a fixed speed set by the line frequency. In contrast, a BLDC with an inverter can use variable frequency and thus can vary its RPM over a wide range. This makes BLDC more suitable for transport and other uses that need a wide range of speeds.

The other advantage of BLDC is using DC power. This is more compatible with batteries, and also with large vehicle systems like electric train grids where power is recovered from regenerative braking.

Answer (score 1):

From the users perspective, a BLDC motor works identically to a brushed DC motor when the commutation is built into the motor. In that case the encoder and transistors functionally replace the brushes, thus making it brushless.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot connect an AC input to a BLDC motor in the way you mean it in your question. The alternating current that the electronic commutator of a BLDC motor generates is a very specific one and synchronized with the rotor position, just as in a brushed DC motor.

The confusion comes from the fact that the terms AC and DC, although so simple when referring to an electric power source, they are ambiguous in the context of electric machines. There are basically two ways to categorize electric motors as AC or DC:

1. Based on whether the input voltage is alternating (AC) or constant (DC).
2. Based on whether the current in the motor electromagnets alternates symmetrically between a positive and a negative direction (AC), or between zero and a specific direction (DC).

Regarding classification #1, any motor with a suitable inverter can operate on either AC or DC input. The only special thing about this classification is that some motors are designed and optimized to work with the available network frequency.